# Cómo puedo sumar una fecha dado un numero y alojarlo en una variable?

Tags: javascript, php

Con este split solo lleno mis cajas de texto. Donde el campo nro_d_tip es un entero y quiero que lo sume solo la parte de los días con la fecha actual. Lo podría hacer en ese mismo script?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function addti(datos) {
        $('#ModalTi').modal('hide');
        d = datos.split('||');
        document.getElementById("id_tip").value = d[0];
        document.getElementById("nom_tip").value =d[1];
        document.getElementById("nro_d_tip").value = d[2];
        }         
        </script>
```

Este es mi formulario

```
<?php   date_default_timezone_set("America/Lima");  
$fecha_actual=date("Y-m-d");  ?>

     <form id="fmem" class="form-persona" method="POST">
      <div class="modal-body">
                                
      <fieldset>
        
      <input type="hidden" class="input_persona" name="id_mem" id="id_mem" />
      <label class="lab_pro">TIPO:</label>
      <input class="input_p" type="text" name="id_tip" id="id_tip" readonly="readonly" />
        
      <button type="button" class="btn-pro" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalTi"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        
      <label class="lab_pro">NOMBRE:</label>
      <input class="input_p" type="text" name="nom_tip" id="nom_tip" />
        
      <label class="lab_pro">DÍAS:</label>
      <input class="input_p"  name="nro_d_tip" id="nro_d_tip" />
        
      <input type="hidden" class="input_p"  name="f_ac" id="f_ac" value="<?php echo $fecha_actual ?>" />
       </fieldset>
        
      <p class="text-center" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-raised btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-paint-roller"></i> &nbsp; LIMPIAR</button>
                                &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <button type="submit" id="guarmem" class="btn btn-raised btn-info btn-sm"><i class="far fa-save"></i> &nbsp; GUARDAR</button>
      </p>
      </div>
     </form>
```

En la parte del botón ahí busco en un modal, y con eso lleno mis cajas de texto. Para ello hago la función que describí al principio.

Comment: Te refieres a algo como "12/12/2021"+1 = "13/12/2021"?

Comment: Si, si es posible, pero esta un poco dificil seguirte el paso con el nombre de las variables. No están muy intuitivas que digamos. Tampoco veo donde quieres poner la fecha actual o en que campo. Puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar comentarios y ejemplos de donde quieres la data y como esperas lograrlo? Aunque no sea programáticamente correcto. Solo para hacerme una idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let diasAAgregar = "30"

document.getElementById("id_tip").value = "Tipo uno";
document.getElementById("nom_tip").value = "Nombre de tipo";
document.getElementById("nro_d_tip").value = diasAAgregar;


let fechaActual = new Date(document.getElementById('f_ac').value)


//Agregamos el dia


console.log({fechaActual})
let fechaActualizada = new Date( fechaActual.setDate(fechaActual.getDate()+(diasAAgregar*1)) ) 

console.log({fechaActualizada})

//Agregamos la nueva fecha al campo ya modificado
document.getElementById('f_ac').value = fechaActualizada
```

```html
<form id="fmem" class="form-persona" method="POST">
  <div class="modal-body">

    <fieldset>

      <input type="hidden" class="input_persona" name="id_mem" id="id_mem" />
      <label class="lab_pro">TIPO:</label>
      <input class="input_p" type="text" name="id_tip" id="id_tip" readonly="readonly" />

      <button type="button" class="btn-pro" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalTi"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>

      <label class="lab_pro">NOMBRE:</label>
      <input class="input_p" type="text" name="nom_tip" id="nom_tip" />

      <label class="lab_pro">DÍAS:</label>
      <input class="input_p" name="nro_d_tip" id="nro_d_tip" />

      <input type="text" class="input_p" name="f_ac" id="f_ac" value="2021/12/12" placeholder="$fecha actual" />
    </fieldset>

    <p class="text-center" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-raised btn-secondary btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-paint-roller"></i> &nbsp; LIMPIAR</button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <button type="submit" id="guarmem" class="btn btn-raised btn-info btn-sm"><i class="far fa-save"></i> &nbsp; GUARDAR</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo mas facil con la libreria **Moment.js**

```
moment().add(7, 'days');
```

https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).